# Displaying two or more sets of aggregate function on a single table

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to display the results of many count functions distinguished by different where criteria side by side.

```
select *
from
(SELECT a.location, count(b.description)
from locations.a left join status b on a.zone =b.zone
where b.date_issued = #1/3/2012#
group by a.location) X
inner join
(SELECT a.location, count(b.description)
from locations.a left join status b on a.zone =b.zone
where b.date_issued = #1/2/2012#
group by a.location) Y
on X.zone = Y.zone;
```

i cannot refer to X and Y in the main select as MS access keeps asking me for a parameter value and if i use Select * i get error in the the from cluase

please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use conditional aggregation.  From the use of `#` for the date constant, I am guessing that you are using Access:

```
SELECT a.location,
       sum(iif(b.date_issued = #1/3/2012#, 1, 0) as val_20130103,
       sum(iif(b.date_issued = #1/2/2012#, 1, 0) as val_20130102
from locations.a left join
     status b
     on a.zone =b.zone
group by a.location;
```

The generic SQL would use `case`:

```
SELECT a.location,
       sum(case when b.date_issued = #1/3/2012# then 1 else 0 end) as val_20130103,
       sum(case when b.date_issued = #1/2/2012# then 1 else 0 end) as val_20130102
from locations.a left join
     status b
     on a.zone =b.zone
group by a.location
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this?

```
select *
from
(SELECT a.location, count(b.description) as Count, a.Zone
from locations a 
left join status b on a.zone =b.zone
where b.date_issued = #1/3/2012#
group by a.location) X
inner join
(SELECT a.location, count(b.description) as Count, a.Zone
from locations a 
left join status b on a.zone =b.zone
where b.date_issued = #1/2/2012#
group by a.location) Y
on X.zone = Y.zone;
```